# ¿Creéis que es malo para el SEO ocultar texto en versión responsive?

Tags: seo

resulta que necesito ocultar un texto pero sólo en la versión móvil, me gustaría que se viese en la versión de escritorio solamente. Es que en la versión de escritorio el texto se puede colocar gracias a que hay más resolución, pero en la versión móvil he de situarlo debajo y ocupa demasiado espacio.

No sé si el robot de Google (o de otros buscadores) tiene en cuenta todas estas cosas, o sólo lo que se muestra en la versión de escritorio

¿Sería perjudicial para el SEO de la página? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Lo que perjudica es hacer dos páginas, una para el visitante de movil y otro para el de escritorio, mientras tanto no... No estás alterando las buenas practicas moviles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google no te va a penalizar por usar diferentes estilos y un diseño responsivo. De hecho, este tipo de [diseño es el recomendado por Google](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/) y no te van a penalizar por utilizarlo, no tendría sentido que lo recomendaran y luego te castigaran por usarlo.

El *crawler* del buscador leerá el contenido de tu página en HTML, procesará tu JavaScript y CSS (puede que ni siquiera eso, aunque Google sí lo hace) y detectará el texto escondido... pero también detectará que ese texto que ese texto es visible en algunos casos y la página no será penalizada.

Ahora, realmente no le daría mucha importancia a esto. Como se dice en las [principios básicos de Google para webmasters](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769): haz tu página para usuarios, no para motores de búsqueda. Google está lleno de gente inteligente, el crawler sabrá diferenciar entre contenido escondido que intenta engañarlos y diseño responsivo/adaptativo.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Álvaro, por aclararme la duda. Es bueno saber estas cosas, y mira que he investigado por internet pero no encontraba solución.

Answer (score 4):

Yo creo que no debería afectar en absoluto porque el texto realmente esta ahí, solo que cuando lo cargas en un dispositivo de ciertas dimensiones simplemente no se muestra, eso claro si el responsive se ha programado en una sola versión de la página.

Si perjudicaría al SEO si tendrías dos páginas distintas, una para versión de móvil y otra para versión de escritorio.

Espero que me corrijan si me equivoco, un saludo.

Comment: Gracias Pablo por tu tiempo, siempre es bueno saber estas cosas.